# Passing automount options in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nfs, autofs

I seem to be unable to automount nfsv4 shares in FreeBSD 10.1.

All of my mounting information is stored in an LDAP database and the shares are on a NFSv4 server.

I've gotten the mapping right so that if I do `automout -L` (shown below) I get the correct mapping; however, I can't seem to see where I would pass in `-o nfsv4`.

`/home/user                             nfs:/user      # indirect map referenced at +auto.home:1`

If I edit `/etc/autofs/include` to try and pass in an option there, autofs doesn't seem to understand what to do with that information.

Any ideas on what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put them into the map entry, or auto_master, just put them on automount and automountd command line, like this: 'automountd -o nfsv4'.  Or just add "-o nfsv4" to automount_flags and automountd_flags in /etc/rc.conf.